# add the response of a google api's address autocomplete into a shinyapp in R

Tags: javascript, r, reactive-programming, shiny

I would like to have the address that is filled in by the autocomplete function in the [javascript+html script](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to be added to a textInput() box in Shiny.  Also, once I have submitted my form with that address I would like the autocompleted address to be reset.  I have some experience in Shiny/R but none in Js.  I'm fairly certain I need to add some lines in js to send information to Shiny but I'm not sure how. My script is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)
library(DT)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("Title", "Description", "Order Type", "Existing", "Due Date", "Address")

gs_auth()
table <- "responses"

saveData <- function(data) {
  # Grab the Google Sheet
  sheet <- gs_title(table)
  # Add the data as a new row
  gs_add_row(sheet, input = data)
}

# Load all previous responses
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type ----

loadData <- function() {
  # Grab the Google Sheet
  sheet <- gs_title(table)
  # Read the data
  gs_read_csv(sheet)
}

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Sign Form"),
    fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    column(3, textInput("Title", "Title", "")),
    column(3, textInput("Description", "Description", "")),



    column(3, selectInput("Order Type", label = ("Select Box"), choices = list("Installation", 
                                                                "Installation/Maintenance",
                                                                "Replace Existing")))


    ),

    fluidRow(
      column(3,checkboxInput("Existing", "Is there an existing sign", FALSE)),
      column(3, dateInput("Due Date", label = ('Date input'), format = "mm-dd-yyyy"))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      **column(3, textInput("Address","Address", includeHTML("www/autocomplete.html")))**


    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(3, actionButton("submit", "Submit"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })

    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })

    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })     
  }
)
```

The line with the autocomplete.html is where I would like some kind of textInput() that is populated when an end user fills in the address form

Here is the [autocomplete.html](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) file it is the example "Javascript + HTML"

Comment: To send javascript variables to Shiny, use `Shiny.onInputChange`, see https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Comment: Yes, I have read this and I can't seem to get it to work for my problem.   I don't understand how to have some objects in the ui.R file pull from the ui itself and for the single field that I need the address for it to pull from the script.